# How to use ScrollView in SwiftUI(not scrolling)

Tags: scrollview, swiftui

```
ScrollView{
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                NavigationLink(destination: GroupDetailsView()) {
                                    GroupView()
                                }
                                GroupView()
                                GroupView()
                                GroupView()
                                GroupView()
                                GroupView()
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 8)
                    }
```

Here's is the code for the scrollview i want to scroll it horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollView (.horizontal){
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                NavigationLink(destination: GroupDetailsView()) {
                                    GroupView()
                                }
                                GroupView()
                                GroupView()
                                GroupView()
                                GroupView()
                                GroupView()
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 8)
                    }
```

- Here's the answer i specified the axis then it worked.